# How do I stop the program from crashing when given a letter in the place of a number?

Tags: python, raw-input

```
employee = float(raw_input('Employee code number or 0 for guest:') or 0.0)

if employee == isalpha:
    print "Nice try buddy"
    print "Welcome BIG_OLD_BUDDY"
```

This code does not recognize alphabetical input.

Comment: That's because you're immediately parsing it as a float. Don't cast a raw value, make it *can* be cast first, probably with a try:except block

Comment: `employee = raw_input('Employee code number or 0 for guest:')`;`if employee.isdigit(): employee = int(employee) else: something else...`

Answer (score 1):

**There are 2 ways.**

> 1. You can catch the the exceptions and pass.

```
try:
    employee = float(raw_input('Employee code number or 0 for guest: ') or 0.0)
except KnownException:
    #  You can handle Known exception here.
    pass
except Exception, e:
    # notify user
    print str(e)
```

> 2. Check for the type of input and then do what you want to do.

```
employee = raw_input('Employee code number or 0 for guest:')

if(employee.isalpha()):
    print "Nice try buddy"
    print "Welcome BIG_OLD_BUDDY"
else:
    print "Your employee no is:" + str(employee)
```

> Do not use try and catch until and unless there are chances of unknown exceptions. To handle things with if and else are recommended.

[Read more about : why not to use exceptions as regular flow of control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control/)

Comment: Try to avoid option 1 unless there is a practical reason for it.

Comment: This error is returned                                                                                                                                                                   

  File "C:\Users\gavin.whitfort\Desktop\2017 Work\Software Devolpment\SAT\POS Solution.py", line 117, in program
    if(employee.isAlpha()):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isAlpha'
>>>

Comment: Right method to check for the alpha is isalpha(). You should do some research on your man.

Comment: @Jerrybibo is right, one should avoid try and catch.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try

```
try:
    employee = float(raw_input('Employee code number or 0 for guest: ') or 0.0)
except ValueError:
    print "Nice try buddy"
    print "Welcome BIG_OLD_BUDDY"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try/except` as the other answer suggested, and if you want to use `str.isalpha()` you have to call it on the string, not compare it with the string. For example:

```
employee = raw_input('Employee code number or 0 for guest:')

if employee.isalpha():
    print "Nice try buddy"
    print "Welcome BIG_OLD_BUDDY" 
else:
    employee = float(employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to only accept **positive integers** you can check using`isdigit()` which is basically the opposite of `isalpha()`.Try:

```
    employee = raw_input('Employee code number or 0 for guest:')

    if employee.isdigit()==False:
      print "Nice try buddy"
      print "Welcome BIG_OLD_BUDDY"
    elif int(employee)==0:
      print "You are a guest"
    else:
      print "Your employee no is:" ,employee
```

I also added a bit of code using `elif` to check if you're a guest